# Syntax for using attr() on individual item from selector array of matches

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call attr() on an item from an array of selector matches, but it's telling me that method doesn't exist. I suppose I need to cast the array item, but I'm not finding how to do this.

```
$("input:radio[id$=Product]")[0].attr('checked', true);
```

The error is "Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'".

Comment: $("input:radio[id$=Product]:eq(0)").attr('checked', true);

Comment: Are you sure `$("input:radio[id$=Product]")` matches anything? It looks like an invalid selector

Comment: If the element has an ID, why don't you just use that?

Comment: @bassxzero - That selector is perfectly fine. The issue is that when you add a `[0]` to a jQuery element, it changes the object to a standard JavaScript element. Plain JS objects can't use jQuery functions like `show()`, `hide()`, or in this case, `attr()`. OP: If you're trying to select the first element, you can use `$(element).first()`, `$("element:first")`, `$(element).eq(0)`, etc.

Comment: @Santi hmmm I thought you needed to quote attribute selectors like `[id$="Product"]` but I guess not

Comment: @bassxzero Nope! I actually just whipped up a quick test to make sure I wasn't going crazy: https://jsfiddle.net/px3rbea8/ - Although, it's good to be in the habit of wrapping them with quotes. If the attribute has characters that could conflict with the selector, then you'll need quotes I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay close attention to the type of the object this expression evaluates to: `$("input:radio[id$=Product]")[0]`.  It is not a jQuery object, so it does not have any jQuery methods.

One solution: wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
$( $("input:radio[id$=Product]")[0] ).attr('checked', true)
```

Another solution (better, I think): use [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to reduce the set of elements to the first one only:

```
$("input:radio[id$=Product]").first().attr('checked', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem causes `[0]`, in jquery you have `:first` option, i.e.
`$("input:radio[id$=Product]:first")`, so maybe this will do the trick.

`$("input:radio[id$=Product]:first").attr('checked', true);`